# Django - FileNotFoundError while running collectstatic with Bower

Tags: python, django

I tried to run collectstatic by pointing to development settings.

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic --settings=socialmkt.settings.dev
```

Now collectstatic does not find the bower_components folder because "settings" was inserted in the path.

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/home/user/Projects/socialmkt/socialmkt/**settings**/static_dev/bower_components'

How do I remove this "settings" from the path for it to find the folder?

> /home/user/Projects/socialmkt/socialmkt/static_dev/bower_components

Comment: Solved! Solution in initial post.

Comment: Recommendation: Can you give the answer in an answer post, please?

Comment: Done! Aswer posted.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=django.conf.global_settings
```

To reset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE config.